# Show that the set $G = Z_4 \times H$ forms a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have come across this problem in my notes.

Let $H = \{−1, 1\}$ equipped with multiplication. Show that the set $G = Z_4 \times H$ forms a group with the following operation:

$$(n, s) \oplus (p, t) = (n + sp, st)$$

I know that $−1\cdot p$ is the additive inverse of $p \in Z_4$, and $1\cdot p = p$. $G$ is in fact isomorphic to $D_4$.

Comment: More generally, let $(A,\cdot_A)$ and $(B,\cdot_B)$ be groups and $\phi\colon B\to \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ a group homomorphism from $B$ to the group of automorphisms of $A$. Then $A\times B$ with $(a,b)\cdot(a',b'):=(a\cdot_A \phi(b)(a'), b \cdot_B b')$ is a group

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ... which is called the "semidirect product" of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A \rtimes B$.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to prove the identity is $(0,1)$ and also that the operation is associative. Something you might need a hint for is the inverse: the inverse of $(n,s)$ is $(-sn,s)$. Otherwise it is "plug and chug," as it were.

Answer (score 1):

You've written down the definition for the "semi-direct" product $\Bbb Z_4\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$.  It requires an homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_2$ to $\rm{Aut}(\Bbb Z_4)\cong\Bbb Z_2$, and there is only one nontrivial one.

The result is non-abelian and it is well-known that this results in $D_4$.

In general, if we define $\varphi:\Bbb Z_2\to\rm{Aut}\Bbb (Z_n)\cong\Bbb Z_n^×$ by $\varphi(1)=n-1$, we get $\Bbb Z_n\rtimes_\varphi\Bbb Z_2\cong D_n$.